# How do I make netrw behave with respects to cycling through buffers with :bprevious/:bnext

Tags: buffers, netrw, plugin-airline

I have my vim setup according to "Solution #1: Replicating Tabs with Buffers" on this site [buffers-vs-tabs](http://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/) with the vim-airline plugin.

If I open numerous files in buffer 'tabs' `:bprevious`/`:bnext` just cycles through them great (and wrap when you get to the end of the 'tabs').

However, as soon as I attempt to use netrw by calling vim on a directory all of the sudden things start misbehaving.

For example, if I execute vim on a directory (`vim .`) and use netrw to drill down a directory hierarchy and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a file, it opens in a new buffer 'tab'.  If I do `:bprevious`, it goes back to the netrw explorer.  If I open another file with the explorer, it opens yet another buffer 'tab' to the right of the first file. `:bprevious` brings me back to netrw, not the file buffer to the left of the of the most recently opened file.  Also when getting back to the file explorer, if I do another `:bprevious`, the cursor just jumps to the top of the netrw window and then doesn't move again with repeated `:bprevious`. Note that during this scenario the netrw is showing up as a buffer 'tab' in the tabline but not highlighted like files.  Also note that the NetrwTreeListing 'count' on the bottom keeps incrementing.

Alternatively, if I execute vim without a directory and just use ctrlp to open some files and then use `:Ex`, A) it does not create a buffer 'tab', it simply displays a buffer/window with the netrw listing and I can open another file and it pops up as the leftmost buffer tab and `:b(previous|next)` works fine.

In either case `:ls!` shows a ton of NetrwTreeListing buffers.

I removed vim-vinegar to make sure it was not due to that and there wasn't really any change but the '-' feature of vim-vinegar does expose this issue as well.

*Note: I apologize for poor terminology with regards to tabs/buffers/windows, but hopefully my explanation makes sense.*

**EDIT:** Things get slightly better if I remove this from my .vimrc:

```
let g:netrw_liststyle=3
```

Sometimes I still get 'stuck' at the file explorer and `:bprevious` stays still.

Answer (score 4):

So this has to do with the fact that:

```
vim .
```

Opens the current directory into a netrw buffer that is not unlisted.  This is what causes odd behavior with `:bp/:bn`.  If I `:bdelete 1` soon as I open vim on a directory, then I don't have this issue for the rest of the session.

Alternatively:

```
vim +':Ex'
```

Does effectively the same thing but with the netrw buffer being unlisted.

I can use an alias to work around this.

But is there way to cause the default behavior of running `vim` on a directory to open an unlisted netrw buffer?

EDIT for more context:

So there are two issues:

A) treestyle netrw (style 3) is full of issues/bugs so I've given up on it.

B) Even with style 0, there is the issue of `vim .` opening the current directory and `:ls!` would show:

`:ls!
  1  h   "~/gitworkspace/temp"          line 1
  2u%a-  "[No Name]"                    line 1`

Note that the first buffer is not unlisted like it should be.

I've come to find that it is due to `set hidden` in my vimrc.  Unfortunately my vim workflow requires being able to edit a buffer and not write it before hopping around to another so I'm unwilling to give that setting up.  Apparently netrw does not play well with that setting.

Answer (score 1):

> as soon as I attempt to use netrw by calling vim on a directory all of the sudden things start misbehaving.

had a similar a problem here, and at least over here, it seemed that the problem was that Netrw was also in the buffer list. In order to avoid that, I'm opening Netrw with:

```
nnoremap <leader>ff :20Lexplore<CR>
```

This way, Netrw won't be added to the buffer list that I'm actually making use of.

Also added this line:

```
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
```

This will make sure that the files won't be opened in the same split where Netrw is.

Should also add that I haven't had problem with the tree style you mentioned. In fact, here is whole block (used in init.vim):

```
 nnoremap <leader>ff :20Lexplore<CR>
 let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
 let g:netrw_banner = 0
 let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
 let g:netrw_altv = 1
```

Since you've mentioned "behavior", you are probably looking for a better workflow. One thing that I had problem with was the fact that closing a buffer and/or a split would destroy how the layout (of splits and vertical splits, each one with its own buffers). So far, the problem was solved with to two mappings:

1 - for ':q' (which is used to quit splits, but mainly to quit Netrw when I'm done with it)

```
nnoremap <C-S>a :q<CR>
```

2 - and another one to delete the buffer, but still keeping the layout.

```
nnoremap <C-A>s :bp<CR>:bd#<CR>
```

This last mapping will change to the previous buffer (':bp') and close the alternate buffer (':bd#') which - in this case - is the one that I really need to close.

Since I did these changes to my workflow, I haven't experienced the problem you have. But I'm not sure what exactely was responsible for that change.